# Schwartz theorem proof from line integral of a gradient over an infinitesimal square

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I am trying to solve Apostol Calculus II problem $10.3.2$, that says the following:

> Given a 2 dimensional vector field 
>   $$f(x,y) = P(x,y)\mathbf{i} + Q(x,y)\mathbf{j}$$
>   where the partial derivatives $\partial{P}/\partial{y}$ and $\partial{Q}/\partial{x}$ are continuous on an open set $S$. If $f$ is the gradient of some potential $\phi$, prove that $$\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{y}} =\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}} $$
>   at each point of $S$.

I have sketched a possible solution (as the problem follows the section on the line integral on a closed path of a gradient, I have tried employing that concept in the demostration). But I am not sure whether my solution is rigorous enough (if anyways correct), so here we are.

Let's take the point $(x_0,y_0) \in S$, and consider $P$ and $Q$ partial derivatives at $x_0,y_0$.

I take the line integral of the gradient $(P,Q)$ over the $h \times h$ square

$$[(x_0,y_0),(x_0+h,y_0),(x_0+h,y_0+h),(x_0,y_0+h)]$$

with $h$ small enough so that the full square is included in $S$ (I can always do that as $S$ is open).

Using t as parameter I get the following

$$\int_0^h{P(x_0+t,y_0)}dt+\int_0^h{Q(x_0+h,y_0+t)}dt+\int_h^0{P(x_0+t,y_0+h)}dt+\int_h^0{Q(x_0,y_0+t)}dt = 0$$

getting

$$\int_0^h{[P(x_0+t,y_0+h) - P(x_0+t,y_0)]}dt  =\int_0^h{[Q(x_0+h,y_0+t)-Q(x_0,y_0+t)]}dt$$

where the two members contain the integral of something that really reminds me of the two quantities I have to proof equal.

That said, I have tried to make the following consideration:

By mean value theorem, for any $h>0$ I can find $0<t_p<h$ and $0<t_q<h$ such that

$$[P(x_0+t_p,y_0+h) - P(x_0+t_p,y_0)]h  = [Q(x_0+h,y_0+t_q)-Q(x_0,y_0+t_q)]h$$
hence
$$\frac{P(x_0+t_p,y_0+h) -P(x_0+t_p,y_0)}{h}  = \frac{Q(x_0+h,y_0+t_q)-Q(x_0,y_0+t_q)}{h}$$
getting rid of integrals.

Then, for $h\rightarrow0$ and definition of partial derivative I have

$$\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{y}}|_{(x_0+t_p,y_0)} = \frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}|_{(x_0,y_0+t_q)}$$

but since $t_p\rightarrow0$ and $t_q\rightarrow0$ as well (as $0<t_p<h$ and $0<t_q<h$) and *because* $\partial{P}/\partial{y}$ *and* $\partial{Q}/\partial{x}$ *are continuous in* $(x_0,y_0)$ I finally get

$$\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{y}}|{(x_0,y_0)} = \frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}|{(x_0,y_0)}$$.

Would this work?

Thanks!

Comment: The penultimate step where you take $h\to 0$ doesn't quite make sense as written, since it looks like you've reverted to infinitesimals, which is a no-no for rigor. Putting aside that you could translate this proof to other points besides $(0,0)$ (after fixing that line with a little work) there was a much easier proof using the fact that second partials commute.

Comment: And I wouldn't pay any mind to the fact that since it follows X section that a method from that section must be employed. Most likely the reason they are having you prove it at the end of this section is because the following section will begin talking about Green's theorem, where the quantity $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ is of utmost importance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! I have nevertheless tried to make it clearer, generic and rigorous. Would you be so kind to review my last edit and tell me if it sounds fine now?

Comment: Your proof was great! I am glad you were able to come up with such a clean idea. Proof aside I do want to stress a point. Technically speaking, your proof works as a great way to prove that the condition holds if the line integral were merely path independent, instead of conservative (while the two are equivalent conditions, that is a fact that has to be proved). To properly use the conservative defintion directly as opposed to detouring to path independence or fundamental theorem of line integrals, the "purist" approach would be to use $\phi_{xy} = \phi_{yx}$.